# how to block url using page rule in cloudflare?

Tags: mysql, nginx, server, cloudflare, ddos

In cloudflare, I know how to write pagerules for filtering URLs. Does anyone know how to block the URLs using the pagerule.It would help me to stop some DOS attack request. for example, I want to block URLs with the following pattern "www.example.com/?". Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Untested but you could try creating a new page rule:

URL pattern: www.example.com/?
Security Level: I'm under attack
Browser Ingetrity Check: On

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a redirection page rule:

URL pattern: www.example.com/?"

Forwarding URLs: https://notfound.404

Comment: No one using a VPN can visit your website. You wrote Single thread debugger, yeah?

Comment: Yes, I wrote a VS extension for that. Which error are you seeing?

Comment: I'm actually contacting you in regards to your website, people who use a VPN cant access it. https://imgur.com/a/w89kE

Comment: I unfortunately had to block several datacenters due to abuse. I'll check if I can improve this in the future.

Comment: Please try again, I have partially lifted the block, I'll monitor if this still causes issues.

Comment: Yes, that fixes it!